# how to prevent backslash while writing json file in pyspark

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I need to write a data into json file like in the below format using pyspark.

```
{
  "list-item": [
    {"author":"author1","title":"title1","pages":1,"email":"author1@gmail.com"},
    {"author":"author2","title":"title2","pages":2,"email":"author2@gmail.com"},
    {"author":"author3","title":"title3","pages":3,"email":"author3@gmail.com"},
    {"author":"author4","title":"title4","pages":4,"email":"author4@gmail.com"},
  ],
  "version": 1
}
```

I have written the below pyspark code but it write "" and adding "" at the beginning and end of each item. How to remove the backslash and double quote

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,to_json,struct,collect_list,lit
from datetime import datetime
from time import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

    schema = StructType([
        StructField("author", StringType(), False),
        StructField("title", StringType(), False),
        StructField("pages", IntegerType(), False),
        StructField("email", StringType(), False)
    ])
    data = [
        ["author1", "title1", 1, "author1@gmail.com"],
        ["author2", "title2", 2, "author2@gmail.com"],
        ["author3", "title3", 3, "author3@gmail.com"],
        ["author4", "title4", 4, "author4@gmail.com"]
    ]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    df=df.select(to_json(struct("author", "title", "pages", "email")).alias("json-data")).agg(collect_list("json-data").alias("list-item"))
    df=df.withColumn("version",lit("1.0").cast(IntegerType()))
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(2, False)
    curDT = datetime.now()
    targetPath = curDT.strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
    df.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").option("escape", "").save(targetPath)
```

my code writes the json with backslash and double quote enclosed each item like below.how to remove those.Please help

```
{"list-item":["{\"author\":\"author1\",\"title\":\"title1\",\"pages\":1,\"email\":\"author1@gmail.com\"}","{\"author\":\"author2\",\"title\":\"title2\",\"pages\":2,\"email\":\"author2@gmail.com\"}","{\"author\":\"author3\",\"title\":\"title3\",\"pages\\":3,\"email\":\"author3@gmail.com\\"}","{\"author\":\"author4\",\"title\":\"title4\",\"pages\":4,\"email\":\"author4@gmail.com\"}"],"version":1}
```

Comment: Try removing `to_json`.  this will return JSON string (converting dict to string).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the type of the elements of the list-item array is string, and the `\` is there to point this fact out.
To avoid that you can try:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("author", StringType(), False),
    StructField("title", StringType(), False),
    StructField("pages", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("email", StringType(), False)
])
data = [
    ["author1", "title1", 1, "author1@gmail.com"],
    ["author2", "title2", 2, "author2@gmail.com"],
    ["author3", "title3", 3, "author3@gmail.com"],
    ["author4", "title4", 4, "author4@gmail.com"]
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df=df.groupby().agg(f.collect_list(f.struct(f.col('author'), f.col('title'), f.col('pages'), f.col('email'))).alias("list-item"))
df=df.withColumn("version",f.lit("1.0").cast(IntegerType()))
df.printSchema()
df.show(2, False)
df.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").option("escape", "").save('./TestJson')
```

and the output json file is gonna look like:

```
{"list-item":[{"author":"author1","title":"title1","pages":1,"email":"author1@gmail.com"},{"author":"author2","title":"title2","pages":2,"email":"author2@gmail.com"},{"author":"author3","title":"title3","pages":3,"email":"author3@gmail.com"},{"author":"author4","title":"title4","pages":4,"email":"author4@gmail.com"}],"version":1}
```